# CSS Triangle with partial fill

Tags: html, css

I want to create a Triangle (preferably using a pure CSS method) that has a two colors. The triangle can be filled to a certain height, this has to be done dynamically on a website as the triangle represents the speed of a device. I want to accomplish the following result:

[image]

The yellow part of the triangle needs to be adjustable. (I don't mind althering the CSS using jQuery but the use of images is a no-go). I've managed to create a triangle using the 'border-method' and I've have managed to partially fill a square using a background linear gradient but the combination of both is proving to be quite a challenge.

```
.arrowLeft{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #5f5f5f;
    float:left;
}
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two triangles and position then relatively:

```css
.arrowContainer{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 100px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #5f5f5f;
    position: relative;
}

.arrowContainer .arrowLeft {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 11px 0 12px 80px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrowContainer">
  <div class="arrowLeft"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the triangular shape using the border and put the gray and orange div behind it using z-index method: https://jsfiddle.net/62yj9wn5/

html:

```
<div class="triangle">
  <div class="vshape">
  </div>
  <div class="orange">
    <div class="gray">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html, body {background-color: black}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  margin: -120px 0 0 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gray {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50px;
  // change the hight dynamically 
  height: 50px;
  }
.vshape{
  width:0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 120px 25px 0 25px;
  border-color: transparent black transparent black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

You can easily reuse those classes if multiply the object and rotate it the "other" 3 directions.